# Dashboard resizing and widgets losing values

Tags: thingsboard

I upgraded from Thingsboard 2.0.2 to 2.1.0. Widgets (vertical digital gauges) suddenly started losing values until next telemetry update or resizing browser manually (showing min value until then). Later I noticed that values where correct about two seconds, and after that dashboard “shrunk” a little as it was trying to fit inside window and the values were gone. Temporary fix was to resize dashboard so it was inside window without need of resizing. I also tried it on mobile devices (iOs and Android) but I was not able to get values neither. So I downgraded back to 2.0.2 where it worked correctly on all devices.  After couple of days I recieved report from user that his dashboard shakes (more like resizes constantly) Temporary fix is still resizing dashboard. On second server where 1.4.0 is running I had no such problem. (Keep In mind that it was tested on the same exported dashboard) 
    Do you have any idea what might be causing this?

Thanks,
Gawain.